# Objective-c: Initialize NSMutableArray with NSString that is plist structure

Tags: objective-c, ios4

If I have a NSString that came back from a web service in the form of a plist structure, how can I initialize a NSMutableArray with this NSString.  I want to know if there is a similar way to initWithContentsOfFile for NSString.

My first thought was to save the NSString to a file and then use initWithContentsOfFile; but I am trying to avoid save to file first. It seems like there should be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, should work like this:

```
NSData *data = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMuableArray *array = [NSPropertyListSerialization
     propertyListWithData:data
                  options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers
                   format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                    error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

See the Property List Programming Guide "[Reading and Writing Property-List Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html)". It covers how to turn `NSData` into a property list. If you already have `NSData` from the network, just don't convert it to `NSString`. If you only have an `NSString`, use `dataUsingEncoding:` to convert it to `NSData`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for the `-propertyList` and `-mutableCopy` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse the XML (which is what a plist is) and turn it into a dictionary (and retrieve the array from there)

Comment: There are more convenient ways than this, luckily ;-)

Comment: This is much better done with `NSPropertyListSerialization` which already does all of what you're describing.